# Как сделать, чтобы fs.access выполнялся синхронно?

Tags: node.js

Пытаюсь настроить задачу в gulp, и мне требуется проверить наличие файла перед выполнением действия. На просторах интернета я нашел fs.access, который для меня имеет несколько странноватую конструкцию, и применил его:

```
  var ret = false;

  //выполняется почему-то асинхронно
  fs.access(target, function(error){
    if (error) {
        console.log("Файл не найден");
          ret = true;
    } else {
        console.log('start less compile for ' + target);
    }     
  });

  console.log(ret);

  if (ret) 
      return -1;  

  return gulp.src(_src_path)
         .pipe(changed(_tgt_path))
         .pipe(less({}))     
         .pipe(gulp.dest(_tgt_path));
```

Но я столкнулся с тем, что ret всегда равен false. А `console.log("Файл не найден");` выполняется после `console.log(ret);`. То есть, насколько я понимаю fs.access создан, чтобы быть асинхронным. Но мне не нужно его асинхронное выполнение в данном контексте.

На просторах интернета так же я натыклся на метод `fs.existsSync`, но он сейчас находится под грифом deprecated, поэтому хочу его избежать (ввиду вероятного его упразднения в грядущих версиях ноды).

Так же натыкался на метод fs.stat, но насколько понял, то там я столкнусь с такой же проблемой, как и с fs.access.

Я так же пробовал с предварительным указанием async для function делать

```
  await fs.access(target, function(error){
    if (error) {
        console.log("Файл не найден");
          ret = true;
    } else {
        console.log('start less compile for ' + target);
    }     
  });
```

но это меня выбросило на `throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`. Собственно вопрос в сабже: как можно с помощью fs.access синхронно узнать, существует ли файл по указанному пути?

Comment: `fs.exists()` is deprecated, but [fs.existsSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) is not.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, точно. Видимо, я их перепутал) Благодарю за поправление. Тогда по сути вопрос скорее решен, чем нет

Comment: что насчёт [fs.accessSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_accesssync_path_mode) ?

Comment: если решён, то отлично.